# Functional analysis: $W=\{x \in X\ |\ \forall f \in W^\bot,\ f(x)=0 \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> $X$ is a linear normed space over the field $K$ and $W$ is a closed subspace of $X$. We consider $W^{\bot}=\{f \in X^*\ |\ \forall x \in W,\ f(x)=0\}$. Prove that: $W=\{x \in X\ |\ \forall f \in W^{\bot},\ f(x)=0\}$.

I think I should find $f$ such that $\ker(f)=W$ but i have found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's just Hahn-Banach. Since $W$ is closed and $\{x\}$ is compact, if $x\notin W$ you can find a continuous functional $\phi\in X^\star$ such that $f(x)>\alpha$ and, for all $y\in W$, $\phi(y)<\alpha$. But for vector subspaces, $\phi(W)\subseteq (-\infty,\alpha)\iff \phi(W)=\{0\}$.

Comment: why $\phi(W)\subseteq (-\infty,\alpha)\iff \phi(W)=\{0\}$?

Comment: Because $W$ is a subspace.

Comment: @T.Nguyen Pick a $w\in W$ such that $\phi(w)> 0$ (why must there be one?) and see what happens to $\phi$ if you follow the straight line containing $w$.